# Is it halal as a sunni to prefer Ali over Abu Bakr, Umar and Othman (Radiallahu anhum)

Tags: ali, khilafah

A salam Alaykum

Basically that is my question, is it halal for sunnis to prefer Ali over them?

Is it halal for me to say that if i was alive i would choose to support Ali for Khalifa over the other Rashidun?

Comment: What do you mean by halal in this context?

Comment: If it is not sinful to be in the position of preferring Ali as a Khalifa more than Abu Bakr, Umar and Uthman and saying it